# Typedef-type inside template class gives compile error

Tags: c++, templates

Real code, stripped to simplest relevant parts:

### 3rd-party code

```
template<class T>
class Ptr
{
private:

    typedef Ptr this_type;

public:

    typedef T element_type;
};
```

---

```
typedef Ptr<DataSet> DataSetPtr;
```

---

### My Code - GPtr.h

```
template<class BaseType>
class GPtr
{
    ///force BaseType to be a Ptr or subclass
    typedef BaseType::element_type WrappedType;
public:
    ...
};
```

If I remove the reference to `BaseType::element_type` it compiles fine, but with it in I get compile warnings/errors:

- warning C4346: 'BaseType::element_type' : dependent name is not a type prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type
- error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'WrappedType'

I am not even *using* `GPtr` anywhere in my code as a specific templated type... simply including gptr.h leads to the problem.

What is wrong here?

Comment: **Read** the warning. It **tells you** what you need to do.

Comment: I never had to do that before, weird

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `typename` disambiguator:

```
typedef typename BaseType::element_type WrappedType;
//      ^^^^^^^^^
```

Without it, the compiler won't parse `element_type` as the name of a *type*.

Comment: How come `Ptr` _doesn't_ have to do this in `typedef T element_type`?

Comment: @John: Because it's not a *qualified*, dependent name: there is no `::` so there is no ambiguity as to how to parse `this_type` - it is obviously a type name. But something that follows `::` could also be the name of a static member variable. The compiler won't parse it as a type name unless you use the `typename` disambiguator